# how to resize text while click on text in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
Container(
          child: Positioned(
            left: offset.dx,
            top: offset.dy,
            child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    offset = Offset(offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                    print('offset $offset');
                  });
                },
                child: Text(_controller.text, textAlign: TextAlign.center, maxLines: 3,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0, color: colorrr)),),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be for you to put the `fontSize` in the `State` of your Widget, and update it from a button or tap somewhere.

Essentially, just like you update the `offset`, you can update a state variable named `fontSize` and use it in your `TextStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

For resize text you may use

dependencies:
auto_size_text: ^3.0.0

import dart code:

import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';

GestureDetector ontap inside use that code :

```
 onTap: () {
            child: AutoSizeText(
              'This string will be automatically resized to fit in two lines.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              maxLines: 2,
            );
```

Hope you will get solution .
Also to know about package: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text/install